# Tools for inspecting element and creating xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

What are the tools available that we can use to inspect the web elements as well as create xpath for web elements?

Comment: For mozila you can use the FirePath (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) plugin.

Its very userful to get the absolute xpath of the specific tag.

Comment: w3schools + developer tools :)  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebug and Firepath in Firefox for firefox below 54 and xpath helper in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

[image: sample image]

In chrome, you can just paste the xpath to find the element.